# I'm trying to set a customizable number range, but the maximum won't work. (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, integer, numbers

So I've made a number guessing game - first half works fine (1-100.) I've created the generated answers to be halfway between the new range. The first guess is 50, if you say lower, the second guess is 25, etc...

I wanted to have a second guessing section once the computer guesses the correct answer - the computer prompts "do you want to play again?" then the user is allowed to create the range.

When I plugged in a min of 1 and max of 400, the first guess was 700. I tried 1 and 100 and the guess was 550. It also no longer abides by the higher or lower rules...

Here is the second half below:

```
console.log("This time you will set the range\n");

let newMin = await ask("What is the minimum number? ");
let newMax = await ask("What is the maximum number? ");
console.log(newMin);
console.log(newMax);

let compGuessA = getSmartIntA(newMin, newMax);
let numAskA = await ask("Is it " + compGuessA + " ?");
while (numAskA === "N") {
    let userDir = await ask("Is it higher 'H' or lower 'L' ?\n");
    userDir = trim(userDir);
    if (userDir === "H") {
        min = compGuessA;
        compGuess = getSmartInt(compGuessA, max);
        numAsk = await ask("Is it " + compGuessA + " ?\n");
    }
    if (userDir === "L") {
        max = compGuessA;
        compGuess = getSmartInt(min, compGuessA);
        numAsk = await ask("Is it " + compGuessA + " ?\n");
    }
  }

start (); //This is all in an async function//

function getSmartIntA(newMin, newMax) {
    let range = Math.floor((newMin + newMax) / 2);
    return range;
}
```

Comment: It looks like `ask()` is returning a promise that resolves to a string, so doing `newMin + newMax` would give the string "1400", which when divided by 2 gives 700, convert `newMin` and `newMax` to nuumbers

Comment: That makes sense!! Thank you so much